# How can I make one part of my code wait for another function to return a Boolean value and then continue execution?

Tags: python, function, discord.py, bots, wait

So I'm making a **discord music bot in python** using **discord.py library**. I want to create a **queue of songs** by creating a function trough which the source to the requested song has to pass. The function checks if the client is currently playing any audio by using **`if vc.is_playing() == True:`** and **if yes then it should wait until** **`vc.is_playing() == False:`** . After the audio is finished playing the function will return the source and another song starts playing.

The question is: **How can I make one part of the code wait for another part to finish executing *(finish playing audio)* and then continue with the execution normally?**

Here is the code of the **incomplete function** that should do the waiting:

```
async def wait_for_url(self, ctx, source, title):
        vc = ctx.voice_client
        while True:
            if vc.is_playing() == True:
                print("@Inside function - 1!@")
                **# Something that waits for client to stop playing should go here!**
                print("@Inside function - 2 - waiting should be over!@")
                time.sleep(5)
                url_final_u = source
                title_u = title
                print("@Inside function - 3 - returning!@")
                return url_final_u and title_u
            else:
                print("@Inside function - A - else condition met!@")
                url_final_u = source
                title_u = title
                return url_final_u and title_u
```

I will also provide code of the **part of my `/play` command** where the above function should be implemented:

```
vc = ctx.voice_client                                                   
self.queue_list.append(url_final_u)                                    
await ctx.send(f"{title_u} has been added to the queue!") 
                                                                          
if len(self.queue_list) > 0:                           
     print("@Before function!")                          
     await self.wait_for_url(ctx, url_final_u, title_u)
     ** # <--- This is the function in question.** 
     print("@After function!@")                       
     if vc.is_playing() == False:
                        
         time.sleep(5)

         await self.play_music(ctx, url_final_u, title_u)
```

All this code is inside a `class commands(commands.Cog)` cog.

I tried to look into `os.wait()` function and even tried asking *GPT 3.5* which had suggested to use **`threading`** **module** with its `.wait()` function and wrote an example code. But when i tried to implement that it just didn't wait for the client to stop playing.

That is if I used **`threading`** correctly as I'm quite new to programming and might have just missed something very obvious, so i will gladly welcome every suggestion that will help me solve this problem.

Comment: It looks like you could do something as simple as `while vc.is_playing(): await asyncio.sleep(1)`. Never call `time.sleep` inside asyncio code (because this prevents other coroutines from running)!

Comment: "How can I make one part of the code wait for another part to finish executing (finish playing audio) and then continue with the execution normally?" - This **isn't actually what you want to happen**, in all likelihood. If one user starts a song playing, then it might be necessary for the bot to keep track of the fact that it's playing; but the bot *should still* respond to other user commands normally (e.g., to put more songs in the queue) - right?

Comment: The underlying issue is that you, presumably, want the bot to *periodically* check whether the song has finished playing, *without* being prompted by a command - so that it can respond to that by starting the next song and taking it out of the queue, or whatever your exact logic will be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you

- Use `asyncio.sleep` instead of `time.sleep`
- Use `asyncio.create_task`

```py
async def wait_for_url(self, ctx, source, title):
    vc = ctx.voice_client
    while vc.is_playing():
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

    url_final_u = source
    title_u = title
    return url_final_u, title_u

async def play_music_with_queue(self, ctx, url_final_u, title_u):
    vc = ctx.voice_client
    self.queue_list.append((url_final_u, title_u))
    await ctx.send(f"{title_u} has been added to the queue!")

    if not vc.is_playing() and not vc.is_paused():
        await asyncio.create_task(self.wait_for_url(ctx, url_final_u, title_u))

        if not vc.is_playing() and not vc.is_paused():
            await self.play_music(ctx, url_final_u, title_u)
```

> Note: Call `play_music_with_queue()` in your code instead of calling `play_music()` directly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Al- Taie. I had to slightly modify the code you wrote but i have managed to make it work! Thanks!